# Antiderivative of $e^{x^3}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I find the antiderivative of $e^{x^3}$?

Basically, I am new to calculus. I hope it is reasonable to make a post here. Thanks!

Comment: No antiderivative exists for this function.

Comment: Did you come across this in some particular context? [This is far from an elementary antiderivative](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e^x^3). If it's in context of an exercise, perhaps let us know about that instead in a different question; there's likely a different approach.

Comment: Since you are new to calculus, it is worth pointing out that "most" expressions in elementary functions do not posses anti-derivatives that can also be expressed in terms of elementary functions without explicitly invoking anti-derivatives.  A good chunk of a calculus course is developing techniques to find anti-derivatives, but even when they exist this can still be a very hard problem.  Compared to all the standard school math that comes before, integration is a lot more of an art than a science.

Comment: I wonder if it could be related to the error function or other special functions.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Of course an antiderivative exists: it is $\int_0^x e^{t^3}\,dt$. Perhaps you wanted to say that this function cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: @egreg Ah, yes of course, that's precisely what I meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sorry to tell you that there is no simple antiderivative for this expression. You have to do it in numerical methods such as Taylor series.

Comment: +1 for using that word "simple".  There is an antiderivative, even if we can't render it readily with our usual suite of "standard" functions.

Answer (score 2):

Notice it has a similar format as $e^{x^2}$, for which no antiderivative exists.